# How to make border of LinearLayout in android as per following design

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: the semicircles are in center and the corners should be rounded, And the background of semicircle should be transparent]
I have uses shape drawable to get rounded coreners but adding a semicircle in between seems tricky.

Comment: Why not use a vector drawable?

Answer (score 2):

you can use vector asset studio to draw a custom shape and use it as background for your layout
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vector Drawable` to achieve your end result. I used [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) to convert your image into `svg` format which is included at the bottom.
Use the `Android Studio` to create a vector drawable from this svg file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="271.000000pt" height="263.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 271.000000 263.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.13, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2015
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,263.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M225 2546 c-40 -17 -84 -63 -101 -103 -12 -27 -14 -228 -14 -1140 0
-1093 0 -1107 20 -1149 12 -24 39 -54 62 -70 l41 -29 456 -3 c251 -2 471 0
489 3 23 4 32 11 32 25 0 11 7 20 15 20 8 0 19 16 25 39 14 54 79 124 142 152
74 33 191 33 265 0 61 -27 125 -92 142 -144 7 -21 17 -37 22 -37 5 0 9 -18 9
-40 0 -40 7 -49 25 -31 6 6 151 11 345 13 l335 3 36 24 c20 14 47 41 60 60
l24 35 3 1105 c1 608 0 1121 -3 1139 -8 42 -59 100 -110 123 -36 17 -73 19
-392 19 l-353 0 0 -35 c0 -24 -5 -35 -15 -35 -8 0 -24 -20 -36 -45 -25 -53
-74 -99 -138 -128 -36 -16 -66 -21 -136 -21 -79 -1 -97 3 -147 27 -90 44 -148
127 -148 211 l0 26 -462 0 c-361 -1 -470 -4 -493 -14z m920 -93 c13 -44 28
-67 70 -109 182 -177 521 -113 592 112 l17 54 335 0 c375 0 383 -1 428 -69
l23 -34 -2 -1113 -3 -1112 -25 -27 c-51 -55 -54 -55 -399 -55 l-319 0 -7 32
c-19 86 -84 160 -180 205 -52 24 -73 28 -150 28 -82 0 -97 -3 -157 -33 -84
-41 -143 -105 -164 -179 l-15 -53 -460 0 c-497 0 -487 -1 -539 55 l-25 27 -3
1111 c-2 1096 -2 1112 18 1145 11 18 34 41 52 52 32 19 52 20 465 20 l432 0
16 -57z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```